# Changing color of cell based on another cells value

Tags: html, css, formatting, conditional-statements

Let's say I have a number of ID's in Column A, a number of dates connected to the ID's in Column B, and another of dates connected to the ID's in column C. All the dates are updated on different occasions. If I want to make a formula for conditional formatting where the color of cells with the value of "0" in Column C are changed, when the same ID has a date on column B.

```
ID   Date1     Date2
VVV  15-07-26  0
```

I want the cell with the zero to have another color.

Comment: Please add a [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to indicate the language or tool you're using (Excel?).

Comment: Ima take a wild guess and say you're working in html or excel? What language are you working in?